# Is it possible to have a different IP address for deployment to Azure Function app than for triggering it?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions

I have a function app with a couple of HTTP-triggered functions. The function app is allowed to accept unauthenticated HTTP requests, which is OK from the security standpoint because it can be accessed only from within a safe closed network - its inbound is configured with private endpoints as in the screenshot below.

Now, I would like to configure some continuous deployment for that function app using Github Actions, whose agents are obviously accessing from outside of my private network. Is it possible to configure a separate public IP that will allow deployments, but not allow any requests triggering the functions?

[image: screenshot-function-app-networking]

EDIT:
Just wanted to clarify that it is not a matter of access restrictions - when a private endpoint is configured then the SCM site is also at that same private address and hence I can only access it from within the private network. I do have an allow-all rule for the SCM site, but it doesn't really matter because the traffic from outside (e.g. Github Actions) will never reach a private address in the first place.
[image: screenshot-scm-firewall]

Answer (score 0):

The deployment to the function app is done via the SCM site which already is a pubic endpoint i.e. my-example-func.SCM.azurewebsites.com. You probably have blocked the access to it from "Access restrictions". To use the Github actions open that up (just for the SCM site). Follow the article about [access restrictions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-ip-restrictions#restrict-access-to-an-scm-site).

Comment: I don't think that's the case - the SCM site (a.k.a. the Kudu service) is listening at the exact same IP as the app, so if private endpoints are configured then it's a private IP. I did add a "allow 0.0.0.0/0" rule in Access Restrictions for the SCM site before but it still gave me 403 when I tried to deploy from outside the private network.